# how to get current request's url in webpy

Tags: python, web.py

I am using webpy framework. I want get current request's url in webpy.

please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try printing `web.ctx` in your controller method and you will see a bunch of environmental variables.

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(web.ctx)
```

So your url probably should be `ctx.home + ctx.path + ctx.query` or `ctx.home + ctx.fullpath`.

UPD: You may also take a look at `web.url` and `web.changequery`, find them in api docs: http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/api

Answer (score 1):

Is [ctx path](http://webpy.org/cookbook/ctx) what you are after?

> **Data Found in ctx**
>
> **Request**
>
> path – the path requested by the user, relative to the current
>   application. If you are using subapplications, any part of the url
>   matched by the outer application will be trimmed off. E.g. you have a
>   main app in code.py, and a subapplication called admin.py. In code.py,
>   you point /admin to admin.app. In admin.py, you point /stories to a
>   class called stories. Within stories, web.ctx.path will be /stories,
>   not /admin/stories. E.g. /articles/845

Comment: thanks, ctx.path only return path, i need the full url. like: http://xx.com/abc/def.asp?abc=xyz

Comment: But there are more attributes than .path: homedomain, query, fullpath... You can build your full url from that bits.